# Get data from URL using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to get data from a website.

```
For Each link In doc.Links
If link.innerText = "fener" Then
link.Click
Exit For
End If
Next link
        While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

Sheets("Final").Range("E5") = ie.document.getElementById("InnerContent").getElementsByClassName("Template")(0).getElementsByClassName("View")(0).getElementsByClassName("Main")(8).getElementsByClassName("Field")(0).innerText

Sheets("Mail").Range("A16") = ie.document.getElementById("InnerContent").getElementsByClassName("Template")(0).getElementsByClassName("View")(0).getElementsByClassName("Main")(9).getElementsByClassName("Field")(0).innerText
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E5") = ie.document.getElementById("InnerContent").getElementsByClassName("Template")(0).getElementsByClassName("View")(0).getElementsByClassName("Main")(8).getElementsByClassName("Field")(0).innerText
```

Site HTML is as below.

```
<table class="Main">
 <tbody><tr class="Main">
  <td class="Literal" nowrap="">ANC:</td>
  <td class="Field" title=""><span class="String">10</span></td>
  <td class="Literal">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="Literal" nowrap="">EDC:</td>
  <td class="Field" title=""><span class="String">20</span></td>
  <td class="Literal">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="Literal" nowrap="">SEE</td>
  <td class="Field" title=""><span class="String">30</span></td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="Main">
  <td class="Literal" nowrap="">ahf</td>
  <td class="Field" title="value"><span class="Changed String">15</span></td>
  <td class="Literal"></td>  <td class="Literal" nowrap="">erd</td>
  <td class="Field" title="erd status"><span class="time">20:45</span></td>
  <td class="Literal">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="Literal" nowrap="">status</td>
  <td class="Field" title=""><span class="String">&nbsp;</span></td>
 </tr>
```

there are many main class in url. In URL, I can find what I want with counting main numbers. (I mean at the first line I chose 8th main in url.
However, I recognised that in one case numbers can change. so is there any way to get data  using nowrap names like "ANC", "EDC" or "SEE"

Also I tried to get entire table from website and see that there is 2 tabe with same id. so when I tried to get both table below code anly gets the first one.

```
For Each Table In ie.document.getElementsByClassName("Main")
Set Table = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("Main")
Set tRows = Table(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
Set tHead = Table(0).getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each h In tHead
Sheet21.Cells(rNum, cNum).Value = h.innerText
cNum = cNum + 1
Next
rNum = rNum + 1
cNum = 1 For Each r In tRows
Set tCells = r.getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each c In tCells
Sheet21.Cells(rNum, cNum).Value = c.innerText
cNum = cNum + 1
Next
```

Comment: What is it you wish to retrieve? And what do you mean by case numbers can change? If there can be some Main followed by Field that are not of interest then you will need to do a loop and test the .innerText of the nodes with classname String for ANC,EDC,SEE

Comment: still nothing works... still need help

Answer (score 1):

If there can be some elements with classname `Main` followed by elements with classname `Field` that are not of interest then you will need to do a loop and test the `.innerText` of the nodes with classname string for ANC,EDC,SEE

```
Public Sub Demo()

    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    html.body.innerHTML = [A3]

    Dim nodes As Object, node As Object, i As Long

    Set nodes = html.querySelectorAll(".Main > .Literal[nowrap]")

    For i = 0 To nodes.Length - 1
        Set node = nodes.Item(i)
        Select Case node.innerText
        Case "ANC:", "EDC:", "SEE:"
            Debug.Print node.NextSibling.innerText
        End Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

If the css selector of `.Main > .Literal[nowrap]` , which selects for child nodes of elements with class `Main`, that have class `Literal` and a `nowrap` attribute, is sufficiently selective then the code becomes simpler:

```
Public Sub Demo()

    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    html.body.innerHTML = [A3]

    Dim nodes As Object, node As Object, i As Long

    Set nodes = html.querySelectorAll(".Main > .Literal[nowrap]")

    For i = 0 To nodes.Length - 1
        Debug.Print nodes(i).NextSibling.innerText
    Next i

End Sub
```

---

Note: I am reading your HTML in from cell A3 in Activesheet.

Requires: VBE > Tools > References > Reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library.

Read about css selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: thanks for the respond. I can connect a website then I get values from there. actually in my code, copy value from website and I paste to activeheet E5. also I edited my code to increse understanding

Comment: Will there only ever be three values? It is easy enough to add a few lines to write to the sheet if that is what is missing from the answer above. Did you try implementing my code and checking it returned the right values?

Comment: 'For Each Table In ie.document.getElementsByClassName("Main")
Set Table = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("Main")
Set tRows = Table(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
Set tHead = Table(0).getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each h In tHead
Sheet21.Cells(rNum, cNum).Value = h.innerText
cNum = cNum + 1
          Next
rNum = rNum + 1
cNum = 1
For Each r In tRows
Set tCells = r.getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each c In tCells
Sheet21.Cells(rNum, cNum).Value = c.innerText
 cNum = cNum + 1
  Next'

Comment: found the issue, in that page there is another main table. so when I try to get data at first main table length is changing. second main table has 20 main line. so I tried to copy entire table to excel. code is as below. however i tried this. code only gets first main table not get the second one. so I really stucked. I also tried your code. actually It does nothing.

Comment: Is there a web address we can test with? The code works for your supplied html. It writes the result out to the immediate window (Ctrl+G)

Comment: web site actually behind firewall, login credentials etc. actually I tried your code. probably I dont understand how to fix this issue. searched web. tried to get table. nothing works.